# Calendar.add not returning expected date

Tags: android, date, calendar, addition

I have the following code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");

Date convertedDate;
String initialDate = "2011-13-05 11:00:00";
try {
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateFormat.parse(initialDate));

cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);

convertedDate = cal.getTime();

String delayDate = dateFormat.format(convertedDate);

} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am expecting delayDate to contain "2011-20-05 11:00:00" but instead it is returning "2012-12-01 11:00:00" and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me both on the desktop and on an Android device. Not sure why you're getting incorrect dates.

EDIT: what specific handset are you using, and what timezone is it in?

Comment: This is on the emulator and the timezone is GMT.

Comment: So I debugged the code again and have realised what I did wrong.  initialDate is passed in as a parameter in my code - I had provided a date in the correct format in the example above but the date format of the passed parameter was yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.